# Why MySQL View return old data after I execute update query on my table data in Spring Boot?

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, view, spring-data-jpa

I have one table and one View depend on the table. After I run update query, Table data gets updated successfully but by the following statement I am fetching data from View, which gives me old data.

```
this.userRepository.save(userData.get());

Optional<UserView> userView = this.userViewRepository.findById(userId);
        
return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(new ResponseEntity<>(userView.get(), HttpStatus.OK));
```

userData.get() has updated data. and View's data stored in userView object, which has old data.

Below is the debug query output which shows that View's query runs first and then update query updates the data. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of is query cache.  You might try:

```
RESET QUERY CACHE
```

If you are not using query cache you might try:

```
FLUSH TABLE
or
FLUSH TABLE <table_name>
```